# CSRF validation fails for certain calls in the same request

Tags: c#, .net, csrf, antiforgerytoken

After login page, the application makes multiple calls to bring up a report. Intermittently, some calls fail with 500 error with underlying message "**A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid**".

It doesn't always happen. Sometimes. the entire request is successful and the report comes up without issues. Other times, I see this anti-forgery error.

We have the same `__RequestVerificationToken` both failed and good calls in the same request. Session ID is the same as well. Any idea why it this issue is happening?

Successful request:
[image]

Failed request:
[image]

Comment: Is your app behind a load balancer, and if so, do you have a centralized place for the validation key?

Comment: There could be plenty of candidates..... Is the backend code you develop or is it something external? What language are we talking about? you talked abou session id so i guess .net ?

Comment: I provided an answer with references, was this helpful? Let me know—this issue should be straightforward to solve. Otherwise, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @pygeek. I am waiting to hear from our client. I will take action once we come to a conclusion

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

The CSRF token is being reused for requests subsequent to authentication A CSRF token is only valid for the initial session. Once authentication occurs, a new session is created and thus a new CSRF token is required.

### TL;DR

You’re seeing an `invalid token` error because the token you’re using is from the session prior to user login

## Solution

Refresh the CSRF token after authenticating user.

## References

Refresh CSRF token after authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#refresh-tokens-after-authentication